# GIT: how to revert back only one historical change while keep others as they are?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

Say I have made changes and committed N times for my project.

After that, suddenly, I found that one change from the N changes causes a problem which has no way to solve.   The only way to solve this problem is to **revert that specific change back**, meanwhile, I need to **keep all the other changes** (both the changes before this problematic change and that after this problematic change) as they are now.

How to approach this in GIT? I mean how to only revert back one historical change and  keep all other changes before and after it

Comment: Are you just using git or are you using git-svn?  In either case, have you already pushed these commits or are they all still local to your system?

Answer (score 3):

Git community book is quite helpful with this sort of thing. The relevant section for you is [here](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html).

The safest choice is to use

```
$ git revert <commit-hash>
```

and resolve any conflicts. You could use `git rebase` to do this, but it rewrites history, and is quite disastrous in repositories that are already pushed or made public. Also, you may want to keep the history that shows you've made a change, and had to change it back. In the long run, it is more informative.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, the safe thing to do is to do `git revert`. This will make it clear that you're "revert"ing that specific change. It will apply a reverse patch to undo the effects of the commit you've provided as an argument.

The other more deadly way is to use `git rebase -i` and drop the "bad commit" in the history. This will rewrite the history from that commit onwards. History of that specific change is excised from the tree but if you've already pushed and others pulled, they will see merge conflicts if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use git revert. This creates a new commit, where all changes of the reverted commit are reverted. This preserves the history.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you had more than *one* change to revert, you also can avoid the editor being opened for each commit you are reverting to:

[`git revert` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-revert.txt):

```
--no-edit
```

> With this option, '`git revert`' will not start the commit message editor.

That makes scripting and chaining multiple revert easier.